# Bash globbing hidden files

Tags: bash, wildcards

I'm trying the following globs in a bash shell:

```
$ ls -d .*
.  ..  .a  .ab
$ ls .a*
.a  .ab
$ ls .[!.]*
.a  .ab
$ ls .[!.]?*
.ab
```

Shouldn't the last expression mean "a dot followed by exactly one non-dot followed by zero or more characters"? Why does it fail to match `.a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mistaken. It means "a dot followed by exactly one non-dot followed by one character followed by zero or more characters". `.a` does not have enough characters to match it.

But really, just set `dotglob`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the question mark referred to the non-dot. No need to set `dotglob`, just playing around. :)

Comment: If you were using regular expressions, then "[^.]?" would mean either a single non-dot character, or no characters.  But in shell globbing syntax "?" matches any single character (basically, "?" in shell globbing is equivalent to "." in regular expressions).